# Adding custom attributes to the breeze entity at client side

Tags: breeze

Is it possible that I add custom fields to the breeze entity object retrieved to client side and remove them before saving the changes back? I need to display an entity object list (Student) in a grid, and the grid has a custom field [Rating], based on his average. The rating I calculate on clientside.

UPDATE:
I tried by overriding the entity constructor as follows:

```
   function overrideStudentEntity(metadataStore) {
        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Student', Student);
        function Student() {
            this.rating = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add Custom field on client side entity

**e.g**  I am Adding fullName from firstName and lastName of student object

var myQuery = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Student');

return manager.executeQuery(myQuery).then(function(studentData){
               studentData.results.fullName=ko.observable();
               studentData.results.fullName(studentData.results.FirstName() +'                    '+ studentData.results.LastName())
           })

Now whenever you fire manager.savechanges() method it will automatic save student object.

Comment: the problem here is, if I have a list of objects in the results, I have to iterate and add the custom field to each object right? Is there anyway I can override the entity constructor and do this? I tried with metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor and its giving me errors.

Comment: `registerEntityTypeCtor` is the right way to do it.  Are you following the [documentation](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/extending-entities)?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: Looks like post-construction initializer is the place to add the calculated or ko.computed rating.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding default JSON adapter, like in "Edmunds" example in no-server examples from GitHub:

https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/no-server/edmunds/app/jsonResultsAdapter.js

http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/JsonResultsAdapter.html

```js
    app.value('jsonResultsAdapter',
      new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({
        name: "edmunds",
        extractResults: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          var results = data.results;
          if (!results) throw new Error("Unable to resolve 'results' property");
          return results && (results.operation.details);
        },

        visitNode: function(node, parseContext, nodeContext) {
          // Make parser
          if (node.isoverdue) {
            // move 'node.models' links so 'models' can be empty array
            // node.modelLinks = node.models;
            // node.models = [];
            return {
              entityType: "request"
            }
          }

          // Model parser
          else if (node.description) {
            // move 'node.make' link so 'make' can be null reference
            node.makeLink = node.make;
            node.make = null;

            // flatten styles and sizes as comma-separated strings
            var styles = node.categories && node.categories["Vehicle Style"];
            node.vehicleStyles = styles && styles.join(", ");
            var sizes = node.categories && node.categories["Vehicle Size"];
            node.vehicleSizes = sizes && sizes.join(", ");

            return {
              entityType: "requestDetails"
            };
          }
        }

      }));
```